# li middle of div and remove shadow top

Tags: css

I have a div that I want to change two things:

**1) REMOVE the TOP shadow:**

```
box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
```

**2) position div nothing in the middle of div NEWS:**

```
.nothing{
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

full css:

```
#news{
 width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000;
 border:1px solid #000;
 box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
 z-index:3000;
}


#news ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#news li{
 padding:10px;
}
.nothing{
 height:100%;
 text-align:center;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1bLdnd06/

thank you friends!

Answer (score 1):

I always use this site to generate the box shadow for you:
http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/

Answer (score 1):

you should edit your css code like this.

```css
   #news{
     width: 140px;
     min-height:100px;
     background: #fff; 
     color: #000;
     border:1px solid #000;
     z-index:3000;
    }
    
    
    #news ul{
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0 ;
    }
    .news li{
     padding:10px;
    }
    .nothing{
     margin-top: 20px;
     padding: 20px;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     border:1px solid #000;
     border-left: 0px solid;
     border-right: 0px solid;
    }
```

```html
<br><br>
<div id=news>
<ul>
<li class=nothing>nothing here</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that not about box shadow, but that look like shadow because there is two line box on top.